# Eclipse crashes

Tags: linux, eclipse

I've been having problems running eclipse. This is the exception that was thrown after the crash today.  I don't understand why I can't run the standard eclipse on my Linux machine. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be? I've tried changing the JVM a hundred times. Messed with the eclipse.ini nothing seems to work.

I'm running Eclipse 64 3.7.1 on RHEL5 AMD64;

```
Exception in thread "Worker-4"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i                                         n thread "Worker-4"
Exception in thread "Keep-Alive-Timer"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i                                         n thread "Keep-Alive-Timer"
Exception in thread "Worker-2"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i                                         n thread "Worker-2"
Exception in thread "Worker-6"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i                                         n thread "Worker-6"
Error while logging event loop exception:
Exception in thread "Worker-3"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i                                         n thread "Worker-3"
Exception in thread "Worker-7"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i                                         n thread "Worker-7"
Exception in thread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i                                         n thread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler"
Exception in thread "Worker-5"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Worker-5"
Exception in thread "Worker-8"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Worker-8"
Exception in thread "Worker-10"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Worker-10"
Exception in thread "Worker-9"
```

I have tried increasing the memory int he eclipse.ini file. Here are some more errors on crash:

```
Error while informing user about event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(
DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(Clas
spathManager.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(Cl
asspathManager.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassIm
pl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_L
ockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(C
lasspathManager.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalCla
ss(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLo
ader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Bundl
eLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(De
faultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(
DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(Clas
spathManager.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(Cl
asspathManager.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassIm
pl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_L
ockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(C
lasspathManager.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalCla
ss(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLo
ader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Bundl
eLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(De
faultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.CollectionFilter.
getInnerIterator(CollectionFilter.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.expression.CollectionFilter.
evaluate(CollectionFilter.java:56)
Dialog open exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(
DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(Clas
spathManager.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(Cl
asspathManager.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassIm
pl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_L
ockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(C
lasspathManager.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalCla
ss(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLo
ader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Bundl
eLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(De
faultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(
DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(Clas
spathManager.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(Cl
asspathManager.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassIm
pl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_L
ockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(C
lasspathManager.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalCla
ss(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLo
ader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Bundl
eLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(De
faultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.openInternalQues
tionDialog(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.openQuestionDial
og(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:194)
Fatal error happened during workbench emergency close.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(
DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(Clas
spathManager.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(Cl
asspathManager.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassIm
pl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_L
ockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(C
lasspathManager.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalCla
ss(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLo
ader.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Bundl
eLoader.java:476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.
java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(De
faultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1277)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchConfigurer.emergencyClose(WorkbenchC
onfigurer.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.closeWorkbench(I
DEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handleException(
IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.access$0(IDEWork
benchErrorHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler$1.runInUIThread(
IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.ja                                  va:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.ja                                  va:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.jav                                  a:667)
Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Logging exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error while informing user about event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Dialog open exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error while informing user about event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Dialog open exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Logging exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Here is my Eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1800m
```

I asked this question again here: [Setting JVM maxperm size outside of Eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072656/setting-jvm-maxperm-size-outside-of-eclipse-ini/9072780#9072780) and received a good answer for anyone else with this problem.

Comment: You might want to rethink your Xms and Xmx settings though. They are really large for normal application development.

Comment: So far no settings are working in the ini file is there another place I can set heap and memory allocation sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be many underlying problems responsible for your eclipse crashing with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Check whether you machine is not low on memory. You can do this with the [`free`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/free) command. Running low on memory would most likely not manifest this way, though, unless you've disabled [overcommit](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting).

Check your per process  virtual memory size limits using the [`ulimit -v`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit) command.

Allow the JVM to grab a larger heap using the `-Xmx` flag.

Your eclipse may be loading a lot of plugins. Each plugin contains a number of classes and all these classes are stored in the permanent generation of the heap. Try to disable some plugins or increase permanent generation size with the `-XX:MaxPermSize` JVM flag.

**EDIT**: Now that the question has been extended with a full stack trace and exception message string, it is apparent that permanent generation size is inadequate. Thus, as suggested above, increase its size with the `-XX:MaxPermSize` or try to disable some plugins. Perhaps you've recently added a plugin which includes a lot of classes?

Comment: For anyone else with the same problem also check out: your problem might be classloader leaks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072656/setting-jvm-maxperm-size-outside-of-eclipse-ini/9072780#9072780

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stating the obvious but it says out of memory, is your computer running low on memory?

Try running it with vm args to allocate more memory.

[eclipse -vmargs -Xmx512m](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm)

Comment: See my updates for my Eclipse.ini maybe you can spot something wrong.

Comment: Run JProfiler and see if you can see where all the memory is going. There is a free trial available here (http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/trial) and eclipse supports that interface by default if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

Going only on this log. As far as I can see this is an Memory size related issue. Have you tried taking a look at the amount of memory given too Eclipse when started? Did you perhaps configure any default JVM parameters. You might check the running Eclipse process with 'ps -aux' from the terminal after Eclipse has started.

You should see something like -Xmx512m or -XX:MaxPermSize=128m. You might also want to take a look at your eclipse.ini to see if some memory related settings is there.

Comment: How does my eclipse.ini look above?

Comment: Could you also state your Eclipse, JVM and OS version. It might be that you've hit this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319514) as stated on the Eclipse [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)

Comment: Eclipse 64 JEE helios 3.7.1 on Linux RHEL5 64