# Setting JVM maxperm size outside of Eclipse.ini

Tags: linux, eclipse

I'm using eclipse64 3.7.1 with Linux RHEL5 64   I have 8gigs of ram.

No matter how large I set the

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

I continue to get errors like:

```
Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.
```

Is there anywhere else I can configure memory options that relate to eclipse and the JVM? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting that exception even after setting the max `PermGen` size to 1024M, it is likely that you have classloader leaks in your application. Increasing the PermGen size will mitigate these exceptions for a while but might not be very helpful for a long-running application.

You might find this article useful: http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java

Comment: Nothing I do to those variables was helping. The only thing that would change was the length Eclipse would remain open and stable. But usually crashed after about 3 minutes of use. I will definitely check that out. Thank you.